# Illegal variable name on SGE, but not locally.

Tags: bash, sungridengine

I have a short bash script running samtools mpileup. It works fine locally, but when I try run it on SGE, I get an "illegal variable name" feedback.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in $(find /bed_files  -name '*.bed' )
do 
name=$(echo $f | awk 'gsub("/", "_")')
name2=$(echo $name | awk 'gsub("_bed_files_", "")')
name3=$(echo $name2 | awk 'gsub(".bed", "")')
samtools runs here 
done
```

Is SGE variable syntax different to bash?

Comment: Sounds like your script is ran under a different shell. Try passing the shell you want sge to use as an argument in your script. I think it might be `-S` but don't quote me on that.

Comment: if possible, edit your question to include actual trace from `set -vx` added before call to `samtools` (followed by `set +vx`) AND include the exact text of the error mesage. Also, you can avoid all the extra process creation by learning about parameter modifiers, i.e. `name=${f//\//_}`  or similar. Good luck.

Comment: Try something like echo "$BASH_VERSION"

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know anything about SGE. However, according to this [link](http://talby.rcs.manchester.ac.uk/~rcs/_linux_and_hpc_lib/sge_intro.html#Job_Shell), you might need `#$ -S /bin/bash` after your shebang line (or else `csh` might be used as default shell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I needed to change the first line to:

```
 #$ -S /bin/sh
```

Comment: Thank you - you probably saved me a lot of stress :).